# MVC AJAX post sending updated model data

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a post request to the Action with the Model data after the value of some of it's properties is changed :

```
@{
  JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings { 
  ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
}

<div id="contents">

    <!--Lead Stage-->
    @if (Model.LeadStagesNav != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.LeadStagesNav.Count; i++)
        {

            @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.LeadStagesNav[i].PermissionId)

            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                @Html.Label("Lead Stage", new { @class = "col-md-2" })
                <div style="display:inline-block;position:relative">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LeadStagesNav[i].Name, null, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px", onchange = "ChangeValue()" })
                </div>

                @if (ViewData["LeadStagesNav[" + i + "].LeadStatus"] != null)
                {
                        <!--Lead Status-->
                    @Html.Label("Lead Status", new { @style = "margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px" })
                    <div style="display:inline-block;position:relative">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LeadStagesNav[i].LeadStatus, null, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px", onchange = "ChangeValue()" })
                    </div>

                    if (ViewData["LeadStagesNav[" + i + "].LeadSubStatus"] != null)
                    {
                        @Html.Label("Lead Sub Status", new { @style = "margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px" })
                        <div style="display:inline-block;position:relative">
                            <!--Lead Sub Status-->
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LeadStagesNav[i].LeadSubStatus, null, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px" })
                        </div>
                    }
                }

            </div>

                <!--Delete Button-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete Lead Stage"
                           onclick="document.getElementById('index').value = @i"
                           name="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="index" name="index" />
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        }

</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

window.ChangeValue = function () {

    var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Formatting.Indented, jss));

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/CmsPermissions/Edit",
        data: { permission: model },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#contents").html(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

the thing is the The problem is that I get the old model data 
posted to the Action instead of the 
new data after the dropdown selected value has changed, 
Anyone has any idea ?

Comment: `var model = @Html.Raw(..` is serializing the original model. You need to serialize your form - `data: $('form').serialize(),` and wrap you form controls in a `<form>`

Comment: But if any of those `if` blocks evaluate to false, this will fail because by default the `DefaultModelBinder` requires collection indexers to start at zero and be consecutive

Comment: And your calling that ajax function every time you select an option in one of the dropdownlists which makes no sense. What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are passing the old model as data

```
 var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Formatting.Indented, jss));
```

you need to serialize your form and pass it an example is

```
function SubmitForm() {
    var data = $("#YourFormID").serialize();
    var url = "/YourURL/ACtion"
    var form = $('#policyForm')[0]
    var formdata = false;
    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData(form);
    }
  return  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formdata ? formdata : data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false, 
        error: function () {
            $('#imgLoadingForPortal').modal('hide');
            Lobibox.notify('error', {
                size: 'mini',
                rounded: true,
                delay: false,
                position: 'center top', //or 'center bottom'
                msg: 'Something went wrong..please try again later',
                sound: false,
                delay: 5000,
            });
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: what is the policyform?

Comment: @YanivJacobJacob instead of policy form put your forms client id

Comment: Im getting model passed as null